# Oracle stored proc - dynamically generate select statement based on optional params

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE get_txn_by_account_id(
p_ACCOUNT_ID IN txn.ACCOUNT_ID%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
) 

IS

BEGIN
FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM txn where account_id=p_ACCOUNT_ID)
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(x.txn_ID || ', ' || x.txn_VER_NB);

END LOOP;
END get_txn_by_account_id;
```

my stored procedure issues a select based on one input as search criteria and outputs the search results.  My input is
ACCOUNT_ID.  I'd like to add 4 additional input params (param_a, param_b, param_c, param_d) - at least two of which will be 
optional.

So I'll probably change my stored proc declaration like

```
PROCEDURE get_txn_by_account_id(
p_ACCOUNT_ID IN txn.ACCOUNT_ID%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
p_PARAM_A IN txn.PARAM_A%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
p_PARAM_B IN txn.PARAM_B%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
p_PARAM_C IN txn.PARAM_C%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
p_PARAM_D IN txn.PARAM_D%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
)
```

So my SELECT may have varying number of query params based on what optional params are passed to the stored
proc.

For instance,

```
FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM txn where account_id=p_ACCOUNT_ID, param_a=p_PARAM_A, param_b=p_PARAM_B, param_c=p_PARAM_C, param_d=p_PARAM_D)
FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM txn where account_id=p_ACCOUNT_ID, param_a=p_PARAM_A, param_c=p_PARAM_C, param_d=p_PARAM_D)
FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM txn where account_id=p_ACCOUNT_ID, param_a=p_PARAM_A, param_b=p_PARAM_B, param_d=p_PARAM_D)
```

or

```
FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM txn where account_id=p_ACCOUNT_ID, param_a=p_PARAM_A, param_b=p_PARAM_B)
```

etc.

I'm having trouble with - how to code my stored proc so that the SELECT statement changes based on what optional params are passed
to the stored proc - perhaps a string builder that builds a query statement based on optional params passed in to the proc, 
and then use the resulting string in the query?  I'm not sure if this is even possible.  Surely this is a common problem - 
anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: why is `p_ACCOUNT_ID` optional? Or to put that another way, what do you want to return if `p_ACCOUNT_ID` isn't provided?

Comment: In that case I'd return an empty set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR x IN ( SELECT * 
           FROM txn 
           WHERE account_id=p_ACCOUNT_ID
             AND (p_PARAM_A is null or param_a=p_PARAM_A)
             AND (p_PARAM_B is null or param_b=p_PARAM_B)
             AND (p_PARAM_C is null or param_c=p_PARAM_C)
             AND (p_PARAM_D is null or param_d=p_PARAM_D) )
```

Comment: The thing is - if for instance, PARAM_A is not passed into the stored proc - I don't necessarily want to search for where PARAM_A is null as part of the join, I'd just like to not include PARAM_A as a query parameter altogether.

Comment: let the optimiser take care of that: the result of `p_PARAM_A is null` is known at compile time.

Comment: or do I misunderstand you: you are *not* searching for `PARAM_A is null` as part of the join if you use my query, you are searching for `p_PARAM_A is null`, which is known to be true in this case at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trick below:

```
select * from FOO
where
  COLUMN_1 = nvl(pParam1, COLUMN_1)
  and COLUMN_2 = nvl(pParam2, COLUMN_2)
  and ...
```

This ensures that if `pParam1` is `null`, your condition always evaluates to `true`. And so on.